# Horizontal and vertical distance between two coordinates on map

Tags: geocoding, geospatial

I have coordinates between two points on the map. There are tools for calculating distance between them, but I want to find horizontal and vertical distance between  the two places. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you points A(x<sub>1</sub>/y<sub>1</sub>) and B(x<sub>2</sub>/y<sub>2</sub>).

The horizontal and vertical distances between the two are the differences of their coordinates:
x<sub>12</sub> = x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>
y<sub>12</sub> = y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>

Addition:
The total distance is
d<sub>12</sub> = sqrt(y<sub>12</sub><sup>2</sup> + x<sub>12</sub><sup>2</sup>)
= sqrt( (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>)

where sqrt means "Square Root"

Comment: this assumes you have a projected coordinate system (i.e. it isn't lat/lon in degrees)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I do not have my data in projected coordinate system. Are there any conversion tools?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your 2 known points A and B have latitude and longitude latA, longA and latB, longB.

Now you could introduce two additional points C and D with latC = latA, longC = longB, and latD = latB, longD = longA, so the points A, B, C, D form a rectangle on the earth's surface.

Now you can simply use distanceBetween(A, C) and distanceBetween(A, D) to get the required distances.

Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62857233/5660341

Answer (score 0):

On the northern hemisphere two positions `a` and `b` would look a bit like:

```
   a--+
  /    \
 /      \
+--------b
```

So there is a common vertical distance, but a slightly different horizontal distance.
The shortest travel would be horizontally from `a` (greatest and then vertical to `b`.

With school math and knowing the zero-height (w.r.t. sea level) ellipse going through both poles you can easily calculate the three distances.

There are sufficient sites, search for longitude, latitude, haversine formula.

There are sufficient simplifications, around, and also one point may be on the northern and the other on the southern hemisphere. And with large values it might be better to horizontally walk left from `a` to the `+`. So you have to really dive into the calculation.

I would not dare to give an actual formula here.