# X Y distance from longitude and latitude

Tags: java, android, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geo

I have two set's of longitude and latitude, i am desperately trying to figure out how many meters point A is displaced from point B, horizontally and vertically.

My goal would be have to +/-X and +/-Y values - I already have the shortest distance between the two points via Location.distanceBetween()....i thought i could use this with the Location.bearingTo() to find the values im looking for via basic trigonometry.

My thinking was i could use the bearing as angle A, 90 degrees as angle C and legnth of Side C (distanceBetween) to calculate the legnth of side A (x axis) and B (y axis) but the results were underwhelming to say the least lol

```
            //CALCULATE ANGLES  
                        double ANGLE_A;
                        ANGLE_A = current_Bearing;                      //Location.bearingTo()
                        ANGLE_A = ANGLE_A*Math.PI/180;                      //CONVERT DEGREES TO RADIANS
                        
                        double ANGLE_C;
                        ANGLE_C = 90;                           // Always Right Angle
                        ANGLE_C = ANGLE_C*Math.PI/180;                      //CONVERT DEGREES TO RADIANS
                        
                         double ANGLE_B;
                        ANGLE_B = 180 - ANGLE_A - ANGLE_C;                  // 3 sides of triangle must add up to 180, if 2 sides known 3rd can be calced
                        ANGLE_B = ANGLE_B*Math.PI/180;                      //CONVERT DEGREES TO RADIANS
            
            //CALCULATE DISTANCES
                        double SIDE_C = calculatedDistance;                 //Location.distanceTo()
                        double SIDE_A = Math.sin(ANGLE_A) * SIDE_C /Math.sin(ANGLE_C);  
                        double SIDE_B = Math.sin(ANGLE_B)*SIDE_C/Math.sin(ANGLE_C);
```

What im noticing is that my bearing changes very little between the two points  regardless of how we move, though mind you im testing this at 10 - 100m distance, its always at 64.xxxxxxx and only the last few decimals really change.

All the online references i can find always look at computing the shortest path, and although this awesome [site](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html?from=64.1265,-21.8174&to=40.7128,-74.0060) references x and y positions it always ends up combining them into shortest distance again

Would SUPER appreciate any pointers in the right direction!

Comment: Hi Corin.  It's not clear if you are asking for help with math or programming.  If it's math you want help with, you probably want to post in https://math.stackexchange.com/.  If its the programming you want help with then try creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Programming - Javascript for Android Studio,

How comes my bearing is barely changing? i've read the docs but i don't understand what angle its actually providing me with.  

I was under the belief the bearingTo() function would provide me with an angle i could use to relate the two Lats/Longs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the earth is not flat, your idea with 90 degree angles will not work properly.

What might be better, is this.
Lets say your 2 known points A and B have latitude and longitude latA, longA and latB, longB.

Now you could introduce two additional points C and D with latC = latA, longC = longB, and latD = latB, longD = longA, so the points A, B, C, D form a rectangle on the earth's surface.

Now you can simply use distanceBetween(A, C) and distanceBerween(A, D) to get the required distances.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this! Very clever and very annoyed i didn't think of this myself!  i do very much appreciate the issues im going to encounter being on the surface of a sphere however i only need this for very short distances <1km (and probably much less in general). Sticking with lat longs and the getDistance() Function should be sufficient for my testing purposes! Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to utilize [Location.distanceBetween()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D)), if following conditions meet,

1. the points are located far apart from polar regions and
2. distance is short enough (compared to radius of the Earth).

The way is very simple. Just fix either longitude or latitude and vary only the other. Then calculate distance.

```
Location location1 = new Location("");
Location location2 = new Location("");

location1.setLatitude(37.4184359437);
location1.setLongitude(-122.088038921);
location2.setLatitude(37.3800232707);
location2.setLongitude(-122.073230422);

float[] distance = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(
    location1.getLatitude(), location1.getLongitude(),
    location2.getLatitude(), location2.getLongitude(),
    distance
);

double lat_mid = (location1.getLatitude() + location2.getLatitude()) * 0.5;
double long_mid = (location1.getLongitude() + location2.getLongitude()) * 0.5;

float[] distanceLat = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(
    location1.getLatitude(), long_mid,
    location2.getLatitude(), long_mid,
    distanceLat
);
float[] distanceLong = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(
    lat_mid, location1.getLongitude(),
    lat_mid, location2.getLongitude(),
    distanceLong
);

double distance_approx = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(distanceLong[0], 2.0) + Math.pow(distanceLat[0], 2.0)
);
```

Compare distance[0] and distance_approx, check whether accuracy meets your requiement.

Answer (score 0):

If your points are close enough, you may easily calculate `x-y` distances from latitude / longitude once you know that 1 degree of latitude is 111km, and one degree of longitude is `111km * cos(latitude)`:

```
y_dist = abs(a.lat - b.lat) * 111000;
x_dist = abs(a.lon - b.lon) * 111000 * cos(a.lat);
```

For short distances we could easily ignore that earth is not exactly a sphere, the error is approximately 0.1-0.2% depending on your exact location.

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid answer to this question until you define what projection.

The azimuth of a "straight" line varies along the route unless you are travelling exactly due south or due north. You can only calculate the angles at each node, or azimuth at a specific point along the route. Angles at the nodes will not add up to 180° because you're referring to an ellipsoidal triangle, and calculating an ellipsoidal triangle is a multiple-step process that in all honesty, is better left to the libraries out there such as OSGEO.

If you want to fit the geometry to a plane Cartesian, it is usually using the Lambert projection for areas mostly long on east and west directions, and Transverse Mercator on longer north to south projections. The entire Earth is mapped in the UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) that will give you Cartesian coordinates anywhere, but in no case will you get perfect Eucldian geometry when dealing with geodetics. For instance, if you go south 10 miles, turn left 90° and go east for 10 miles, turn left 90° again, you can be anywhere from 10 miles from your starting point, to exactly back to where you started, if that point happened to be the North pole. So you may have a mathematically beautiful bearing on the UTM coordinate plane, but on the ground, you cannot turn the same angles as the UTM geometry indicates and follow that same path on ground. You will either follow a straight line on the ground and a curved line on a cartesian plane, or vice-versa.

You could do a distance between two points on the same northings and separately, the same eastings, and derive a north distance and an east distance. However, in reality the angles of this triangle will make sense only on paper, and not on the globe. If a plane took off at the bearing calculated by such a triangle, it would arrive in the wrong continent.

Comment: Hey i really appreciate this answer, its detail is immense and its really helped me to understand the complexity i'm dealing with. 

I had considered looking at UTM but i think you've saved me a lot of wasted time! I owe you one buddy!

Comment: Geodesy is an interesting topic. Don't get me started on geoids. Throw elevations into the mix, and now the definition of what up is, or what level is goes out the window. Mean sea level is lumpy, and "down" points in all sorts of different directions, depending on the density of the surrounding land masses.